# receive the value from link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Good day everyone. Have a problem with realization one situation. I have some links let say 5 (but it can be more than that). Every link have id="#link", but I also have a 5 different variables. So I need some how receive one of that variables in jquery depending of the link that will be click on. How can I realize it?

```
<?php
$a=1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$d=4;
$e=5;
printf ("<a href=\"\" id=\"#link\">link_a</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" id=\"#link\">link_b</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" id=\"#link\">link_c</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" id=\"#link\">link_d</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" id=\"#link\">link_e</a>");
?>
```

So here is 5 variables - a, b c d e, and 5 links, so I need to recive one of that variables depending of the clicked link;

```
$(document).on('click','#link',function() {

alert(result);
return false;
});
```

P.S. Numbers of variables and links can be more than 5. It can be 10 or 20. But I take 5 for an example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't assign same `id` to multiple links in order to achieve such functionality you need to use `class`

Comment: I use your idea and make them class="link" and made them id= variable, then I use in juery - var result = this.id; and that it . Thank your coment was usefull

Comment: Glad it helps you. Posting it as an answer @alex_mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a need to store *data* in the anchor (HTML) elements.

[Data attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) is the way to go.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$a=1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$d=4;
$e=5;
printf ("<a href=\"\" class=\"mylink\" id=\"#link\" data-variable=\"$a\">link_a</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" class=\"mylink\" id=\"#link\" data-variable=\"$b\">link_b</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" class=\"mylink\" id=\"#link\" data-variable=\"$c\">link_c</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" class=\"mylink\" id=\"#link\" data-variable=\"$d\">link_d</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" class=\"mylink\" id=\"#link\" data-variable=\"$e\">link_e</a>");
?>
```

IDs within an HTML document, should be unique. Use classes if you have a need for redundant identifiers.

**Javascript Code:**

```
$(document).on('click','a.mylink',function() {
    //Use .attr() to get the data attribute.
    alert($(this).attr('data-variable'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I use some thing similar to that, I solve it (read comments after post), But thanks for your help

Comment: I highly disrecommend the usage of `id`s to store data. Please use the data attributes, since they are semantically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Modification of you code

```js
<script>
  function get(){
  var m=$(this).val();
  alert(m);
  }
</script>
```

```html
<?php
$a=1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$d=4;
$e=5;
echo "<a href='' onclick=get() value=".$a." >link_a</a>";
echo "<a href='' onclick=get() value=".$b." >link_b</a>";
echo "<a href='' onclick=get() value=".$c." >link_c</a>";
echo "<a href='' onclick=get() value=".$d." >link_d</a>";
echo "<a href='' onclick=get() value=".$e." >link_e</a>";
?>
```

It will work for fine as per your requirements.

Comment: Link has no attribute `value`.

Comment: I tried do it with value but I can't get result, BUt because of the coment after my post I realize it very simple just by using the id as you use the value. and just var result = this.id; But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead of `ID` (or use just `a` element) and put PHP variables into any data-attribute.

```
<?php
$a=1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$d=4;
$e=5;
printf ("<a href='' class='link' data-value='" . $a ."'>link_a</a>");
printf ("<a href='' class='link' data-value='" . $b ."'>link_a</a>");
printf ("<a href='' class='link' data-value='" . $c ."'>link_a</a>");
printf ("<a href='' class='link' data-value='" . $d ."'>link_a</a>");
printf ("<a href='' class='link' data-value='" . $e ."'>link_a</a>");
?>

<script>

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
a.onclick = function() {
    alert(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign same `id` to multiple links in order to achieve such functionality you need to use `class`
Its because id's were need to be unique

```
<?php
$a=1;
$b=2;
$c=3;
$d=4;
$e=5;
printf ("<a href=\"\" class=\"link\" data-id=\"$a\">link_a</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" class=\"link\" data-id=\"$b\">link_b</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" class=\"link\" data-id=\"$c\">link_c</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" class=\"link\" data-id=\"$d\">link_d</a>");
printf ("<a href=\"\" class=\"link\" data-id=\"$e\">link_e</a>");
?>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click','a.mylink',function() {
    alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
//or you can directly use it as 
    alert($(this).data('id'));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).on('click','#link',function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: You should try it first before you write an answer.